# Exclude email address from a list of excluded domains

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have an email client that lists emails like you see in the gmail inbox.

All the emails are store in a Postgres 9.3.5 database.

Part of the functionality I want to implement is to allow users to block incoming emails from a list of domains, e.g. @spam.com,

I have [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6ce80/10) sqlfiddle which contains a cut down version of the schema, I have an `emails` table and an `email_participants` table.  The user can choose to select as many domains they want to exclude, for example they could choose to exclude emails from yahoo.com, hotmail.com etc.

Currently the query is basically this:

```
SELECT subject, ep.email_id, kind, ep.user_id, ep.contact_id
FROM emails e
INNER JOIN
email_participants ep
ON ep.email_id = e.id
-- and ep.address domain doees not include *.yahoo.com, *.hotmail.com or whatever
WHERE kind = 'sent'
ORDER BY sent_at DESC;
```

I want to store the excluded domains in a table but I have no idea how to exclude with a like query from a set of data.

Comment: Your emails table has `account_id integer NOT NULL,  sender_user_id integer,  sender_contact_id integer`. How about some explanation what's what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't exactly right, but close enough to get you there... try:

`and substring(ea.address from '@.*') not in ('@yahoo.com', '@hotmail.com')`

In context:

```
SELECT subject, ep.email_id, kind, ep.user_id, ep.contact_id, ea.address
FROM emails e
INNER JOIN
email_participants ep
ON ep.email_id = e.id
JOIN email_addresses ea
ON ep.contact_id = ea.contact_id
and substring(ea.address from '@.*') not in ('@yahoo.com', '@hotmail.com')
WHERE kind = 'sent'
ORDER BY sent_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

> The user can choose to select as many domains they want to exclude

This suggests that in the back-end you would need a table that has user_id & exclude_domain as columns:

```
CREATE TABLE user_excludedomain (
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    domain VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_excludedomain_pkey PRIMARY KEY (user_id, domain),
    CONSTRAINT user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Then in your select query, add a `left join` to this table & structure the `where clause` to remove rows where the join yielded a row from this table.
i.e.

```
SELECT
    e.subject, 
    ep.email_id,
    e.kind,
    ep.user_id,
    ep.contact_id
FROM emails e
INNER JOIN email_participants ep 
    ON ep.email_id = e.id
-- left join all domains to be excluded
LEFT JOIN user_excludedomain uex 
    ON uex.user_id = ep.user_id 
    AND uex.domain = SUBSTRING(ea.address from '@.*') 
WHERE kind = 'sent'
  AND uex.user_id IS NULL -- pick only rows where the left join returns null (i.e. the excluded domain is not joined)
ORDER BY sent_at DESC;
```

Comment: Won't this select addresses from the blacklist instead of excluding them?

Comment: `uex.user_id IS NULL` excludes the email addresses with blacklisted domains.